# Why do JButtons that open webpages only work the first time one is clicked and then get deactivated?

Tags: java, swing, url, jbutton

I have a set of JButtons, each of which opens a separate YouTube video webpage. When first running the program, I can click on any ONE button and get the video page. When I try to get another video page with a button click, it doesn't work - in fact, all the buttons are deactivated. This is the case whether or not I close the video webpage.

How can I keep all the buttons activated? Thanks in advance.

Here's the code for reference. The button links and tags are populated from a text file.

```
//import statements

public class VideoRecord extends JFrame {

private File videoRecordFile;

public VideoRecord() throws FileNotFoundException {
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
    setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    videoRecordFile = new File("videorecord.txt");      
    getButtons();
    pack();
}

public void getButtons() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(videoRecordFile);
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        Scanner lineInput = new Scanner(input.nextLine());
        while (lineInput.hasNext()) {               
            final String urlString = lineInput.next();
            String buttonText = lineInput.next();
            JButton btn = new JButton(buttonText);
            add(btn);
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                    
                    try {
                        URL videoURL = new URL(urlString);
                        URLConnection videoConnection = videoURL.openConnection();
                        videoConnection.connect();
                        openWebpage(videoURL);
                    } 
                    catch (MalformedURLException mue) {} 
                    catch (IOException ioe) {}
                    setEnabled(false);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

public static void openWebpage(URI uri) {
    Desktop desktop = Desktop.isDesktopSupported() ? Desktop.getDesktop() : null;
    if (desktop != null && desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
        try {
            desktop.browse(uri);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void openWebpage(URL url) {
    try {
        openWebpage(url.toURI());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    VideoRecord vr = new VideoRecord();
}
```

}

Comment: From your question's title, I guessed that your code would have empty catch blocks. I sadly see that I was correct. Please fix this, at least print out the stacktraces, and you'll likely find the problem and then its solution. As a general rule, you should almost **never** have empty catch blocks like you do above.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with `setEnabled(false);`?  Don't blindly throw away your exceptions, they provide important and useful information

Comment: @MadProgrammer: that should be an answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm trying not to get involved

Comment: I think the setEnabled would just effect the one button that was clicked in the first place. No other buttons work after the first one gets clicked.

Comment: @RobinK. But what does `setEnabled` belong to...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a second to look at you code...

```
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                    
                try {
                    URL videoURL = new URL(urlString);
                    URLConnection videoConnection = videoURL.openConnection();
                    videoConnection.connect();
                    openWebpage(videoURL);
                } 
                catch (MalformedURLException mue) {} 
                catch (IOException ioe) {}
                setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
```

When you click a button you call `setEnabled(false);`...

This has actually disable the frame, not the button that was clicked...

1. Try using `((JButton)e.getSource()).setEnabled(false)` instead
2. Don't throw away you `Exception`s blindly, they provide important and useful information that can help solve problems

Comment: Does it affect all buttons? I just want the one clicked button to be disabled but the other ones should keep working. It keeps me from watching the same video twice, supposedly.

Comment: Glad you got involved... 1+

Comment: `setEnabled` is a method of `JFrame`, you've disabled the frame...consider using something more like `((JButton)e.getSource()).setEnabled(false)` instead...

Comment: @RobinK.: but still, I stand behind my recommendations regarding those empty catch blocks.